# Weird Open SSH server behavior in one of the two NICs

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-22.04, sshd

I have a brand new Ubuntu setup (fossa) over an old mac mini (late 2012) with both on board NICs (wired and WiFi). Open SSH works flawlessly in the wired interface but it hangs just after login on the WiFi interface with both password and key authentication methods. WiFi and Wired interfaces are connected to different networks (wired connected to home router network, wifi connected to segregated wireless network on a dd-wrt router).

If sshd is listening to "all" IPs (as default), I should be able to connect to either IPs, but when logging in to the WiFi IP, *just after it authorizes the user* and creates the session, *the ssh client hangs most of the times*, but not always, very few times it connects just to be really slow, hang again or resets the connection from the WiFi IP address. The same host performs as expected when ssh'ing through the wired IP.

I tried *disabling firewalls* (all together in the ubuntu server and WiFi router) along with any *packet filtering or QoS* rules for the WiFi network.

To validate that it's not any WiFi configuration I setup *2 virtual machines with NICs bridged* to the WiFi in the host and setup open-ssh servers in both.  Both windows and linux *clients connect flawlessly to the open-ssh servers in both the Linux and Windows virtual boxes* (through the WiFi interface). The host's wireless NIC is accepting SSH packets and redirecting them to the VMs. Additionally, pings to the WiFi NIC to the host and the VMs (even with 2024 and higher byte counts) perform nominally.

I compared **default sshd configuration files** from the Linux VM with the Ubuntu Host (same release) and they are identical.

I also tried configuring the client to keep alive and max tries with no effect whatsoever (which was somehow expected as no client tweaking is needed for the wired NIC).

Note that scp works fine in both NICs with either authentication methods (ssh key and user credentials). I can upload and download files to and from the ubuntu host connectig to both IPs.

The issue is still that the ssh interactive session hangs in the WiFi interface.

The sshd config file is not provided as it's the default that comes with open-ssh.

Here are the "-vvv" logs for user crendentials and key authorization. Logs are edited to reduce size (only some repetitive strings where replaced by elipsis).

**Using User Credentials:**

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.10.1.136 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.1.136 [10.10.1.136] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: ... id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: ... id_dsa type -1
debug1: ... id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: ... id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: ... id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: ... id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: ... id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: ... id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: ... id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: ... id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: ... id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: ... id_xmss type -1
debug1: ... id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.10.1.136:22 as 'rod'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from 10.10.1.136
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:UpajCzkWpEY+rABSsQsM/EtdLPmTwPUaaaTX+EJZsAo
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from 10.10.1.136
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '10.10.1.136' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: ... id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: ... id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: ... id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: ... id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: ... id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: ... id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: ... id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: ... id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: ... id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: ... id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: ... id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: ... id_xmss
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.10.1.136 ([10.10.1.136]:22).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug3: This windows OS supports conpty
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:437 to 65001
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:wgRflddWQCkLnvYT3X+cOvLLzKm3zBDhcDgo8M4w4ww
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:bTHWEiVD3X2cYeMWmn5SDigAKbXC6kghwfGNkDnN2CA
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:UpajCzkWpEY+rABSsQsM/EtdLPmTwPUaaaTX+EJZsAo
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts for 10.10.1.136 / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key at C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2 for 10.10.1.136 / (none)
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 0 new, 3 retained, 0 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 4/5/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 437
debug3: fd 2 is not O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 8.
```

**Using SSH Keys:**

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.10.1.136 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.1.136 [10.10.1.136] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa_aws type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/id_rsa_aws-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/id_rsa_aws-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/id_rsa_aws-cert error:2
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa_aws-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.10.1.136:22 as 'rod'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from 10.10.1.136
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:UpajCzkWpEY+rABSsQsM/EtdLPmTwPUaaaTX+EJZsAo
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from 10.10.1.136
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '10.10.1.136' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: .ssh/id_rsa_aws RSA SHA256:8n6avlHGnEwPwCcnON39Uh8yLoKod6X5cvzYteT1XCg explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: .ssh/id_rsa_aws RSA SHA256:8n6avlHGnEwPwCcnON39Uh8yLoKod6X5cvzYteT1XCg explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: .ssh/id_rsa_aws RSA SHA256:8n6avlHGnEwPwCcnON39Uh8yLoKod6X5cvzYteT1XCg explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:8n6avlHGnEwPwCcnON39Uh8yLoKod6X5cvzYteT1XCg
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:8n6avlHGnEwPwCcnON39Uh8yLoKod6X5cvzYteT1XCg
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 10.10.1.136 ([10.10.1.136]:22).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug3: This windows OS supports conpty
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:437 to 65001
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:wgRflddWQCkLnvYT3X+cOvLLzKm3zBDhcDgo8M4w4ww
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:bTHWEiVD3X2cYeMWmn5SDigAKbXC6kghwfGNkDnN2CA
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:UpajCzkWpEY+rABSsQsM/EtdLPmTwPUaaaTX+EJZsAo
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts for 10.10.1.136 / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key at C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2 for 10.10.1.136 / (none)
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file C:\\Users\\rmort/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 0 new, 3 retained, 0 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/rod/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/rod/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 4/5/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 437
debug3: fd 2 is not O_NONBLOCK
```